# Implementation of Clientside Authentification with Apache James

Tags: java, apache, ssl, x509, james

i am using Apache james as a mailserver and i need to implement both side Client- and Serverside Authentification with X509 certificates.

The serverside is pretty easy and only a matter of configuration in the config.xml - but how about clientauth?

Is there a simple way of implementing this by config?
In the sockets-Area of the config.xml i can set the authenticate-client to true, but the James wiki says i am only allowed to put only one certificate in the keystore provided under the keystore-section:

```
 <factory name="ssl" class="org.apache.avalon.cornerstone.blocks.sockets.TLSServerSocketFactory">
        <authenticate-client>true</authenticate-client>
        <ssl-factory>
           <keystore>
              <file>conf/@KEYSTORE_FILENAME@</file>
              <password>@KEYSTORE_PASSWORD@</password>
              <key-password>@PRIVATEKEY_PASSWORD@</key-password>
              <type>JKS</type>
              <protocol>TLS</protocol>
              <algorithm>SunX509</algorithm>
           </keystore>
        </ssl-factory>
     </factory>
```

So if you have some recommendations on how to do this or know a tutorial that deals with this, i would really appreciate if you could share it.

Thank you!

Comment: Turns out the above described way works fine, just hat some certificate issues!

Comment: can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put all your certificates in the keystore if you like. But since i needed a clear sepparation of key- and truststore i changed the sources of james so it was possible.

Unfortunately there is no simpler way of doing this.